# Using a node module with Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, postmark

I have a very simple meteor application.
I want to utilize the postmark api in this application lucky for me they have a node.js module.
https://github.com/voodootikigod/postmark.js
I have successfully installed this module to node and can see it sitting there.
Every resource I have touched on has told me that this should now be accessible via Meteor with a simple require.
This is my code so far.

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Welcome to postmarkapp.";
      };

      Template.hello.events({
        'click input' : function () {
          // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
          if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
            Meteor.call('sendMail',function(error,result){
              console.log(result);
            });
          }
      });
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
    postmark = require("postmark")('API_KEY');
        Meteor.methods({
          sendMail: function() {

            return postmark;

          }
        });

    }
```

Now I don't get any errors when I run this method however I do get an empty object with no methods. Looking at the postmark module I should get an object with one method, "send".

Can anyone enlighten me on where I could be going wrong? I think it may be in the including of the node module and the use of that module in the Meteor app.

I have looked at the documentation of Meteor extensively and cant seem to find anything related to this subject.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [2013 Meteor NPM Packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is trying to return the `postmark.send` function to the client.  This is not possible.  Methods can only return JSON serializable values.

You should be able to use postmark's `send` function inside the method body, though depending on its interface you might need to wrap it in a fiber.